# storing multidimensional array in session in codeigniter and retrieving it using foreach

Tags: php, codeigniter, multidimensional-array

This is my code in controller

```
function index()
{       

$data=array();
$data = array('product_id'=>$this->input->post('product_id'),
                'quantity'=>$this->input->post('quantity'),
                'unit'=>$this->input->post('unit'),
                'unit_rate'=>$this->input->post('unit_rate'));

                $this->session->set_userdata('data',$data);
                    $post_array[]=$this->session->userdata('data'); 


?>
<table>
<tr>
<th>Product  Name</th>
<th>Quantity </th>
<th>Unit </th>
<th>Unit Rate</th>
<th>Action</th>
</tr>
<?php
$i=0;
foreach($post_array as $cart)
{
    //echo "<pre>"; print_r($cart); echo "</pre>";
    $query = $this->db->query("SELECT product_name FROM phppos_product WHERE
 product_id='".$post_array[$i]['product_id']."'");
    foreach ($query->result() as $row)
{
$product_name=$row->product_name;

}
    echo "<tr>";
    echo "<td>".$product_name."</td>";
    echo "<td>".$post_array[$i]['quantity']."</td>";
    echo "<td>".$post_array[$i]['unit']."</td>";
    echo "<td>".$post_array[$i]['unit_rate']."</td>";
    echo "<td><a href='javascript:void(0)' rownum='".$i."' class='remove_from_cart'><img
  src='images/close.png'/></a></td>";
    echo "</tr>";
    $i++;
    }
?>
 <tr>
<td></td>
<td></td>

<td></td>
</tr>
</table><?php
 }
```

I am storing `$data` array i.e single dimensional array in session and trying to append it to two dimensional array i.e. `$post_array['cart'][]`. And I am trying to retrieve it using `foreach` loop. It gives me errors like `undefined index` and `illegal offset string` etc. So how do I solve this??

**I edited my code. This gives me exactly what I want but it's somewhere wrong. I dont know can anyone tell me?**

This is my print_r($post_array) output

```
 Array
(
  [0] => Array
    (
        [product_id] => 2
        [quantity] => 1
        [unit] => 12
        [unit_rate] => 100
    )

)
```

Comment: This is really controller ? vardump your first foreach or print_r. Read the structure thats you will know how many time you need to looping it.

Comment: Yes I know I used html tags in controller..

Comment: @Nucleo1985 please see my edit above...

Comment: can you post the print_r from the first loop ? to see the structure? var_dump is fine.

Comment: what should I print_r?

Comment: @Nucleo1985 see my edit above

Comment: try change to this foreach($post_array as $cart => $val) and print_r the $val, what you got ?

Comment: Or use online php editor & debugger i will fix it. Your code above pretty mess, i cant get it really clear.

Comment: Ok ..I got that working but my problem is it add's only one row. when I try to add second row it replaces first row in table.

Comment: So the foreach declaration is wrong. Find better resource to debug the code with dummy data.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/67889/discussion-between-nucleo-1985-and-kedar-b).

Answer (score 0):

You need your `index()` function to return your `$post_array` array to the main script, otherwise it's not visible in the main script's scope; to do so you need first of all to change your `index()` function definition accordingly, by adding this at the end:

```
return $post_array();
```

Then you can call `index()` into your main script before your `foreach` statement in order to store its return value into `$post_array`:

```
$post_array = index();
```

Comment: @KedarB You are still not calling `index()`, look at my updated answer for details on why this is mandatory for your design

Answer (score 0):

Its Always better to serialize any data before storing it to session, it can the be put to a session simply as a string. It can easily be accessed and de-serialized whenever needed.